# Cannot show the result from Php file in Android

Tags: php, android, json, phpmyadmin

I have a problem about getting value from php file and showing it as a Toast message.

I get result value as "null".

How can I fix it?

Here is my php code.

```
...
$x = (array('Result' => "Successful"));
echo json_encode($x,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
...
```

android code

```
x.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Result result = response.body();
                    String message = result.getResult();
                    Log.i(LOG,"gonder() | onResponse : " + message);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: does your response prints the value your required?

Comment: @Lakhwinder Singh No,it doesn't show the "Successful" , it shows only just "null".

Comment: i am asking about the logging interceptor of Retrofit, does it prints your request and response as desired? Obviously in logcat

Comment: check with some REST tool, like postman, if the server responds correctly first

Comment: @Lakhwinder Singh there is no problem in Retrofit part. I get null value from json_encode

Comment: In andriod just check what value you are getting for response.body().getResult().  before using Toast

Comment: @Shivendra Singh  null value

Answer (score 0):

In php use the json_encode

```
$x = (array('Result' => "Successful"));
echo json_encode($x,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

And In android before showing the response message as as a Toast message  you can check you are getting the Successful message or not.

Like.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
    @Override            
    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
        if(response.body().getResult().equals("Successful")){
          // add your code here to showing messawge as a Toast.
        }
        else {
          // display error
        }
    }
    @Override            
    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {//display errror message

    }
});
```

Comment: Normally, the response message has a value named for "Successful" but it shows "null" value.

Comment: In php you are getting the response in correct json format. i think you have need to check android code.

Answer (score 0):

My answer,

I changed the variable as "result" instead of defing "Result" and I fix the issue.

```
$x = (array('result' => "Successful"));
echo json_encode($x,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```